# Payload vs Custom field on LineItemEntity

Tags: shopware, shopware6

The `LineItemEntity` in Shopware has a `payload` field and a `customFields` field. Both are of the type JSON. When should one use `payload` for storing data and when `customFields`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`payload` is populated when the line item is still in the cart, so **before** an order has been placed and is kept when the cart is converted to an order. For instance the property contains meta data of the original product and may be used to store such data that is used across the checkout. The payload ideally shouldn't be changed after the cart has been converted to retain the original state of the order.

`customFields` contains the system specific [custom fields](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/custom-fields) that can either be populated by api or the administration. They can be used to attach data **after** an order has been placed. Custom fields should be [properly created](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field#add-custom-fields-to-an-entity) first.